# Setting values of $ u$ in $H^{1/2}$ on a set of zero measure

Tags: fractional-sobolev-spaces, trace-map

everyone

If I set values of $u \in L^2(\partial \Omega)$, $\Omega \subset R^3$, at several points on $\partial \Omega$, I will not not define $u$, because it is a set of zero measure.

Am I correct that it holds for $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ ? That is, does prescribing $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ on a set of zero measure define $u$?

I would appreciate a reference to a textbook. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand what it means to set values of $u\in L^2(\partial \Omega)$, or $H^{s}(\partial\Omega)$. Furthermore you only do so "at several points"? How? Measure zero w.r.t which measure, Lebesgue on $\mathbb R^3$?  Or Hausdorff on $\partial\Omega$?  I suppose you mean you want the trace of $u$ on $\partial\Omega$ to be in $L^2(\partial\Omega)$?

In any case, the values on the boundary never uniquely define an arbitrary function in any Sobolev space. This non-uniqueness can be directly seen by the existence of smooth, compactly supported functions. Namely, both the zero function and any [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) supported inside $\Omega$ have zero boundary values.

Perhaps you are thinking of solving Poisson's equation, or more generally a second order elliptic PDE. Here's Poisson:

\begin{align} -\Delta u &= f \\ u|_{\partial \Omega} &= g \end{align}
Weak solutions to this (which are unique) are in $H^1$  if say $f\in H^{-1}$ and the boundary is $C^1$, so here we need $g$ to be the trace of a $H^1$ function. Such functions are indeed in $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$.

To solve this, you first convert this into the homogeneous boundary equation by subtracting off a function $G\in H^1$ whose boundary values is $g$, say $G|_{\partial \Omega} = g$, $v := u - G$:
\begin{align} -\Delta v &= f + \Delta G\\ v|_{\partial \Omega} &= 0\end{align}
and then you can apply the theory developed in Chapter 6 of Evans "Partial Differential Equations" to get a weak solution $v\in H^1$ and therefore $u\in H^1$.

Comment: Let me put it in this way. Say, we are solving the Poisson's equation as you wrote it (the first one), but instead of demanding the trace of u be equal to g, we demand the trace of u AT A SINGLE POINT \in \partial \Omega be equal to, say, 1. This formulation does not make sense, and I would like to see why.

Comment: @lumberman this is answered by the above result. Its unique when you specify boundary values on the whole boundary as a $H^{1/2}$ function. There are many $H^{1/2}$ extensions of a function defined at a single point. Each extension gives a different $u$. Ergo you don't define $u$ uniquely.

Comment: Ah! I see. So it boils down to the fact that an extension from a single-point value to $H^{1/2}$ is not unique (perhaps it would be the correct re-formulation of my initial question). Now I wonder if it holds for a finite set of points (and then: what about a line on the boundary?) . Could you, please, recommend a textbook on this "extension-related" matter? Thank you !

Comment: @lumberman The way I understand your worries, there is nothing that actually cares that the set $\partial \Omega$ is actually the boundary of some other set. (Especially since you do not prescribe a manner in which to extend to the rest of $\Omega$, like  solving a certain PDE, or otherwise). In fact, there is nothing about Sobolev spaces in your question. The nonuniqueness happens for smooth functions on a domain. You should look into bump functions to answer those questions. A book like Evans' PDE treats bump functions in its appendix, you can find many others like wikipedia by googling